logging.getLogger cannot get the logging config info
I have two .py files: main.py and utils.py.
The main.py will import funciton from utils.py
My plan is that the log info in both .py files can be recorded in the same log file
Here is my code:
in the main.py:
from utils import run
import logging

# log setting
log_path = './logs'
if not os.path.exists(log_path):
    os.makedirs(log_path)
full_log_path = log_path + '/model-' + 'p2p_check-' + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.localtime()) + '.log'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    handlers=[logging.FileHandler(full_log_path, 'w', 'utf-8'),
                              logging.StreamHandler()])

run()

in the uitls.py:
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def run():
    logger.critical('Logger handlers: %s', logger.handlers)

    logger.info('This is an info message from the submodule.')
    logger.debug('This is a debug message')
    logger.info('This is an info message')
    logger.warning('This is a warning message')
    logger.error('This is an error message')
    logger.critical('This is a critical message')

However, no log will be recode in my log file and part of log info in utils.py will output on my screen:
Logger handlers: []
This is a warning message
This is an error message
This is a critical message

It seems that the getLogger function cannot get the logging config on the main.py. How to fix this issue?

The logging system is federated. Unless configured otherwise a message is passed up the tree like structure of loggers to the root logger, which in your case hold the handler(s). The sub-logger you queried is "empty".
